# Cannot get environment variable in Inno Setup preprocessor, when executed in Docker

Tags: docker, environment-variables, inno-setup

Locally environment variable is printed well:

```
bash-3.2$ echo $APP_VERSION
2.0.3
```

But when I try to get this environment variable in my Inno Setup file, it behaves like this environment variable doesn't exist:

```
Error in Z:\work\inno\app-win-x64.iss: The [Setup] section must include an AppVersion or AppVerName directive.
Compile aborted.
```

This is how I use it:

```
#define MyAppVersion GetEnv('APP_VERSION')
// ....
[Setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
// ....
```

*Environment:*

- Inno Setup 6.0.5
- OS: MacOS Catalina 10.15.6
- Running with the command below in *bash*.

```sh
docker run --rm -i -v "$PWD:/work" amake/innosetup inno/app-win-x64.iss
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, guys, I have found the cause of this problem. The problem is that I work on Mac and to compile Inno Setup I use the following command:

```sh
docker run --rm -i -v "$PWD:/work" amake/innosetup inno/app-win-x64.iss
```

But I forgot to pass environment variable to the container. So, all what I need is to pass `APP_VERSION` to `docker run` command. This works for me:

```sh
docker run --env APP_VERSION=$APP_VERSION --rm -i -v "$PWD:/work" amake/innosetup inno/app-win-x64.iss
```